# How to create a textNode in HTML?

Tags: html, dom

I want to create a textNode directly in HTML (with no javascript), and I need a reference to it.

Is it possible ?

If not, what would be the best workaround ?

I see 2 possibilities :

1/ Wrapping the text in a div (or span or whatever) element ? Not so good as it impacts selectors.

2/ Wrapping the text between 2 dummy elements (cf emberjs :

```
    <script id="metamorph-0-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
    blue
    <script id="metamorph-0-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
```

) ? With this solution you get the reference to the textNode by taking the element(s) between the 2 "metamorph" elements.

Comment: Text nodes can't have IDs as far as I know. That's what `<span>` elements (or any other element really) are for.

Comment: How does a DIV impact selectors?

Comment: @JCOC611 You are right I am updating my question

Comment: @Šime Vidas For example if I have a CSS rule on ".test", with a new element (div or whatever) the class will not apply.

Comment: @Simon Well, you set it on the DIV, e.g. `<div class="test">`, if you want the rule to apply.

Comment: Yes there are workarounds, but they have a cost and the second suggestion is already "cleaner".

Comment: @Simon How is using two dummy `<script>` elements cleaner than just using a `<span>`?

Comment: It is because they are here only to find the textNode. They don't actually contain the text. You can even remove them after having found the textNode.

Comment: @Simon But if you'd put the text in a `<span>`, then that SPAN would serve the same purpose. I don't see why it's a problem that the SPAN contains the text. What difference does that make?

Comment: It is not a problem. But I want to avoid adding additional elements.

Comment: Better solution is to use comment nodes, they don't impact CSS rules and are lighter.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `span` here:

```
<script id="metamorph-0-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
<span id="myTextNodeID">blue</span>
<script id="metamorph-0-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
```

Comment: No, in fact adding an element is the first suggestion I made.